# Interactive World Map with leader names of each country and administrative division

Tags: mapping, interaction

Is there any interactive World Map with country leaders, also the administrative divisions? Starting with presidents/heads of state and prime ministers and all the way down to town mayors.

In usual maps you see the **countries and administrative areas name labels** when zooming, instead I would like to see **people's names who are in charge**. Does this exist? After googling, it appears that this does not exist. I've only found maps for joking such as this map below, but nothing serious and complete.

### [image]

Comment: Think about some of the challenges to this - keeping it up to date at the smaller levels, how do you determine which name to put. For example, in the UK do you use the queen or the prime minister, or what about areas governed by a council rather than a single individual? But this conceptually is a really cool idea!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably something you can pull out of Wikidata.

This long URL goes to a query that retrieves countries sorted by age of leader (for those over 65):

https://query.wikidata.org/#%23List%20of%20countries%20by%20age%20of%20the%20head%20of%20government%0A%23added%20by%20Jura1%2C%20rev.%202016-11-08%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fage%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fhgovernment%20%3FhgovernmentLabel%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3624078%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ3024240%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20p%3AP6%20%3Fstatement%20.%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20ps%3AP6%20%3Fhgovernment%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP6%20%3Fhgovernment%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20NOT%20EXISTS%20%7B%20%3Fstatement%20pq%3AP582%20%3Fx%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%3Fhgovernment%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fdob%20.%20BIND%28YEAR%28now%28%29%29-YEAR%28%3Fdob%29%20as%20%3Fage%29%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fage%3E%3D65%29%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Fage%29

so the data is there. This is one of the example Sparql queries, and I'm no Sparql expert. I'd maybe try and modify this to get an ISO country code and then join that up with a world map (eg a shapefile) with ISO country codes and then label by leader name.

A wikidata/sparql wizard could probably do this all within Wikidata, but it would take me a bit more work to do in QGIS or R.

Comment: Oh thanks! Maybe there are RSS feeds that public administrations use to provide their organizational data (people, structure, etc)? Any web service? Is there any standard on that?

Comment: Wikidata is probably the greatest semantically structured database around, and with the right SparQL query I think you could generate the map straight away (it does have mapping functions). I doubt there's a standard that each nation is going to implement independently though, maybe the UN has a data feed or something? If I had an hour or two I'd go through the full process from the above query to a web map.